# How do I define method signatures for dynamically added methods?

Tags: typescript

My app supports third party plugins.
I have methods throughout my app, which I want to collate under a single "API" class in order to present them to plugins.

For example, I have a `Todo` class with a `deleteTodo(id)`. At runtime I introspect the Todo class and add all of its methods to the API class. So I end up calling the equivalent of

> API['deleteTodo'] = Todo['deleteTodo']

My plugin can now happily call `API.deleteTodo(id)` which all works fine.

However, tsc emits `2339: Property 'deleteTodo' does not exist on type 'typeof API'`, which I'm having to `//@TS-IGNORE`. Is there a simple way that I can define a method signature for `API.deleteTodo` to remove the error and give plugin authors auto-complete on the API methods?

I've tried having API implement an interface with those methods defined, but that made no difference. Adding an interface...

> class API implements Todo

... gives `2420: class 'API' incorrectly implements 'Todo'. Property deleteTodo is missing...`.

If I add it with a Partial...

> `class API implements Partial <Todo>`

... I still get the `2339: property 'deleteTodo' does not exist...`

For Aaron...

```
function deleteTodo() { }
class API {}
API['deleteTodo'] = deleteTodo;
API.deleteTodo();  // This succeeds at runtime, but tsc gives 2339: Property 'deleteTodo' does not exist on type 'typeof API'
```

Comment: Can you show a complete example? Your last sentence sounds like it should work.

Comment: @AaronBeall see edits

Comment: There's still a lot of parts you aren't showing, it's hard to tell what you need. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @AaronBeall I've turned the question into a 4 line code snippet for you. I look forward to your suggestions.

Comment: You are assigning static methods (`API.deleteTodo()`) not instance methods (`new API().deleteTodo()`). Unless you have class methods or properties you don't need a class here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few things going on here...

```
function deleteTodo() { }
class API {}
API['deleteTodo'] = deleteTodo;
API.deleteTodo();  // This succeeds at runtime, but tsc gives 2339: Property 'deleteTodo' does not exist on type 'typeof API'
```

That example assigns static class methods (`API.deleteTodo()`) not instance methods (`new API().deleteTodo()`), and [interfaces cannot define static properties](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13462). However, unless you actually have some instance methods or properties (ie you use `new API()` somewhere) there's no reason to use a class here at all.

It's not completely clear from your examples if you have a pre-determined order of execution. In other words, are you *sure* that `API` will have all the methods before *anywhere* uses `API.deleteTodo()`? If so then I would define the `API` type separately and use assertions to avoid compile errors in the code where you build the value:

```
// Define the API
interface API {
  deleteTodo(): void;
}

// Build the implementation
function deleteTodo() { }
const API: API = {} as API; // use `{} as API` to allow initializing an empty object
API["deleteTodo"] = deleteTodo; // fill in the API methods

// Now you can use it without any assertions
API.deleteTodo();
```

Or if you really need to use a class for some reason:

***Edit by OP: This is the answer for my use case...***

```
function deleteTodo() { }
interface API {
  deleteTodo(): void;
}
class BaseAPI {

}
BaseAPI["deleteTodo"] = deleteTodo;

type APIClass = { new(): BaseAPI } & API;

const API = BaseAPI as APIClass;

new API(); // No use for this in your examples, but if you have a use for it...
API.deleteTodo();
```

Also:

> At runtime I introspect the Todo class and add all of its methods to the API class.

It's not clear if the `Todo` class APIs are known ahead of time or not. If not, then the above will not be possible. If so, then I'm not sure why you are introspecting the `Todo` class at all, when you could just build it statically:

```
function deleteTodo() {}
function otherMethod() {}
function etc() {}

const API = {
  deleteTodo,
  otherMethod,
  etc
}

API.deleteTodo();
API.otherMethod();
API.etc()
```

Comment: that worked a treat - many thanks. 
The reason it's so convoluted is that as well as writing all code myself, my goal is to allow end users to write simple snippets which will be calling the API methods, which themselves could be contributed by external third parties. It all works well, but I wanted to also take advantage of TS code completion for snippet authors, which your answer achieves for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could have `API` implement the plugin classes with `Partial` to allow the methods to be `undefined` until you attach them:

```ts
class API implements Partial<Todo>, Partial<SomePlugin> {

}
```

Unfortunately you would need to check if a method is attached before you can use it:

```
if(api.deleteTodo) {
  api.deleteTodo(todo);
}
```

You could also use `as` to cast an `API` instance into `API & Todo`:

```
const api = new API() as API & Todo;
```

This could lead to errors where the compiler thinks `api.deleteTodo` is a function, but at runtime it's `undefined`.